# Question marked as duplicate of question with no answers

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have posted a question on Stack OverFlow a couple of hours ago. It was a duplicate of another question (posted about 3.5 years ago) which I knew (actually posted a link to that question in my post) but that question only had one answer which was not very satisfying. After 3-4 mins my question received about 4 downvotes with my question marked as duplicate.

So even if the question was posted about 3.5 years back and does not have any reliable answer. Was my question still supposed to be marked as duplicate? What if it was answerable now?

Question Link: [How to detect the hand user holding his device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135811/how-to-detect-the-hand-user-holding-his-device)

Comment: I don't see any of your questions are marked as duplicates. Presumably, since the target question was closed as too broad, so too is your duplicate. Besides, this is a question about a specific Stack Overflow question, so should be asked at [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Indeed, never closed as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19135811/timeline

Comment: "no answers that I like" is not "no answers" as you have said in your title

Comment: @KateGregory you answer cleared things up for me..  i didnt know that you can bring up the old answer to the front page. thanks. Not sure why i am still getting downvotes thou.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you find a question that is **just the same as yours** except that it doesn't have good answers, the solution is **never** to just ask it again. If yours is truly different (different version of the software, perhaps) then ask a question, link to the original, and emphasize the difference so people don't close yours as a duplicate

Assuming no difference, your options are:

- if the original is poorly asked, edit it to improve it. This will also bump it to the front page.
- comment on the answer saying why it's not satisfactory. This will ping the answerer, and they might improve it. If they edit their answer you may get what you want, and also that will bump the question to the front page
- add a bounty saying you're looking for better answers
- promote the question yourself (use the *share* link and you might even get a badge) on twitter or whatever other way you have of shouting out to the world.
- don't forget to upvote the question, which may increase the likelihood of someone clicking on it from the front page

All of these approaches might work. They might not, after all this is probably something pretty obscure. But asking a duplicate that gets closed, downvoted, and probably deleted definitely won't work. Work with the system the way it works. What you want is an answer to that 3.5 year old question. These are ways to get that.

Comment: It is a duty of site owners to explain why they close the question. Just closing by noticing same key word is not enough. Wait. There is no presumption of innocence for mere mortals. Site owner can declare the question duplicate no matter what. Your attempt to prove otherwise is an aggravating factor. Mortals must foresee and respond to all nitpicking in advance. If the question is duplicate, you do not ask it. Otherwise, you just ask your question. You cannot reference "a duplicate" because your question unique. You reference something only if want to build up on something.

Comment: Not sure I understand this comment, @LittleAlien, but 5 high rep users (not site owners) can close as dupe, and 5 others can re-open. Mistakes are easily fixable. It's not about innocent/guilty, and you can edit to make distinctions clear if you weren't aware of similarities. Your comment appears to argue with or dispute the fairness of policies that don't actually exist.

Comment: The actual policy is the way I drawn it. People just do not look what you write. They look at your key words and insist on their blindness. For instance, I asked if there is a difference between inventation and discoverty in philosophy (a discipline that deals with general knowledge, I believe) and they closed telling that there is question in math "if math is invented or discoveried". They did nothing even when I highlighted that my question is not limited to math, that it is more general. It was ridiculous to hear that mine is worse and duplicate because it is more narrow.

Comment: It is more narrow and is not about math because I wanted them to tell me about the problem that I see even in the math answers, making it very different. They also closed my last Q at meta.SO and removed it, despite I clearly highlighted them how distant they are.

Comment: So, you formalize us the ideal ethics, I tell you about the real moderation, which is opposite to the declared ideals. Also, ideally, if question is duplicate it should not be asked. It should be clear from the question what you ask, if you ask the same thing or different one. It makes no sense to point out how it is diff from every other Q on the earth. It must be obligation of the answers to reduce the asked question to existing one, highlighting the difference. You only answer the difference and redirect the rest to the "duplicate". Your answer seems to support the current criminal stance.

Comment: "criminal" ? We're done here.

Comment: Sure it is done. Everybody must welcome such behaviour and pretend that it is something good. If you don't -- you are amoral outcast.

Answer (score -5):

Duplicate is duplicate. It does not matter which formal reason you find that it is not a subject to be duplicate. The only reason for duplicate must be a substance. My questions are often marked with "duplicate", despite often they are not, when there is substantial differences that you want to ask about. Otherwise, it makes no sense to post the same question over and over again. It makes sense to link those questions to reduce the redundancy (known as DRY to you), save space, labour and simplify the world we live in. I bet there must be a better way to re-quest the answers for an old question, without posting a duplicate. Instead of creating a duplicate, you had to comment why that answer is bad/unsatisfactory. "Duplicate" means that others will have the same problem as well.